# Does Python's split function splits by a newline or a whitespace by default

Tags: python, string, split, python-3.6

I am learning Python. In particular, i read about the python string's split method and [came to know](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp) that the default separator for `split` is a whitespace. So i understand how the following works:

```
text = 'Hello World'
print(text.split())   #this should print ['Hello', 'World'] which it does
```

The output of the above program in Python3.6 is `['Hello', 'World']` as expected because in the above string variable `text` we have whitespace.

But then i tried out the following example:

```
text = 'Hello\nWorld'
print(text.split())    #this should print ['Hello\nWorld'] but it doesn't
```

The actual output of the above is:

```
['Hello', 'World']  #this shouldn't happen because there is no whitespace in text
```

While the expected output of the above is:

```
['Hello\nWorld']    #this should happen because there is no whitespace in text
```

As you can see, since there is not whitespace between `'Hello'` and `'World'` the output should be `['Hello\nWorld']` because `\n` is not a whitespace and a whitespace is the default separator for `split` method.

What is happening here.

Comment: new lines are considered [whitespace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.whitespace)

Comment: `text = 'Hello\nWorld'` `print(text.split(" "))` will return `['Hello\nWorld']`

Comment: I'm not really sure why this was downvoted, I guess people thought this was easy to find an answer to in the docs but thats only the case if you knew to look for pythons definition of whitespace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If sep is not specified or is None, a different splitting algorithm is
> applied: runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single
> separator and the result will contain no empty strings at the start
> or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace.

Tabs (`\t`), newlines (`\n`), spaces, etc. They all count as *whitespace* characters as technically they all serve the same purpose. To *space* things out.